# Error in creating spatial Index using Spring Data neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-spatial

I'm working on Neo4j Spring Data project and wants to perform some spatial related operation on nodes.

**Entity Class**

```
@NodeEntity
public class User {

@GraphId
Long id;
private String fname;
private String lname;
private String uname;
private String pwd;
private Double latitude, longitude;

@Indexed(indexType = IndexType.POINT, indexName = "geom")
private String wkt;

public void setLocation(Double lon, Double lat) {
    this.wkt = String.format("POINT( %.2f %.2f )", lon, lat);
}
@RelatedTo(type = "KNOWS", direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
public Set<User> knows;
//getter and setter methods
```

**Controller**

```
  @RequestMapping(path = URI_SAVE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleUriSave(@ModelAttribute(value = "insuser") User user) {
    System.out.println("save method called");
    System.out.println("User : " + user);
    try {
        User retrivedUser = userService.findUser(user);
        if (retrivedUser != null) {
            if (retrivedUser.getUname().equals(user.getUname())) {
                throw new Exception("User Already Exist !!");
            }
        }
        user.setLocation(user.getLongitude(), user.getLatitude());
        userService.create(user);
```

**UserServiceImpl**

```
    @Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements IUserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserEntityRepository userrepository;

    @Override
    public User create(User user) {
        return userrepository.save(user);
    }
```

**UserEntityRepository**

```
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepository;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.SpatialRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.ga.data.entity.User;

@Repository
public interface UserEntityRepository extends GraphRepository<User>, SpatialRepository<User> {

    User findByUname(String uname);

}
```

At the time of saving the user it gives exception,

**EXCEPTION**

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Erroraddingelement0wktPOINT(85.4225.02)toindexgeomstatus500{
        "message": "No such property, 'wkt'.",
        "exception": "NotFoundException",
        "fullname": "org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException",
        "stackTrace": [
            "org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy.getProperty(NodeProxy.java:469)",
            "org.n
    xNodeWrapper.addNode(LegacyIndexNodeWrapper.java:52)",
            "org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.StateHandlingStatementOperations.nodeAddToLegacyIndex(StateHandlingStatementOperations.java:1420)",
            "org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.Ope
    LegacyIndexProxy.java:390)",
            "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.DatabaseActions.addToNodeIndex(DatabaseActions.java:699)",
            "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.RestfulGraphDatabase.addToNodeIndex(RestfulGraphDatabase.java:1059)",
            "
    java:745)"
        ],
        "errors": [
            {
                "code": "Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownFailure",
                "message": "No such property, 'wkt'.",
                "stackTrace": "org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: No such property, 'wkt'.\r\n\tat org.neo4j.kernel
    x.add(LayerNodeIndex.java:41)\r\n\tat org.neo4j.gis.spatial.indexprovider.LegacyIndexNodeWrapper.addNode(LegacyIndexNodeWrapper.java:52)\r\n\tat org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.StateHandlingStatementOperations.nodeAd
    egacyIndexProxy.internalAdd(LegacyIndexProxy.java:536)\r\n\tat org.neo4j.kernel.impl.coreapi.LegacyIndexProxy.add(LegacyIndexProxy.java:390)\r\n\tat org.neo4j.server.rest.web.DatabaseActions.addToNodeIndex(Data
    reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)\r\n\tat com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(
    her.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)\r\n\tat org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:139)\r\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl
    ri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)\r\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)\r\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.appl
    9)\r\n\tat com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)\r\n\tat com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)\r\n\tat
    ervletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:800)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)\r\n\tat org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CollectUserAgentFilter.doFilter(Coll
    a:221)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1125)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.serv
    ndle(HandlerList.java:52)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.
    a:620)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:540)\r\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\r\n"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I am new to neo4j DB. I have read some articles and created index via REST API in neo4j but creating with spring data neo4j gives this type of exception.
I'm using neo4j-community-2.3.1-windows version and spring-data-neo4j 3.4.0 RELEASE version.

Any Suggestion Please.

Comment: Hey Niraj, could you please update the question to include the Neo4j versions you're using please? Also, what does 'userService.create' do? Could we see that code too please?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of spring-data-neo4j are you using? Are you using spring-data-neo4j-rest? Or embedded within the server?

Was this a user which existed before?

In the exception there seems to be a bit of stacktrace missing.

Can you repoduce it with a unit test?

Comment: The stack trace suggests the REST version:

```org.neo4j.server.rest.web.RestfulGraphDatabase.addToNodeIndex(RestfulGraphDatabase.java:1059)",```

Comment: Hi Michael, In my pom I have added
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
   <version>3.4.0.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-rest</artifactId>
   <version>3.4.0.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
And No there were no any user existed before.
May be my approch was wrong as i'm new to this and created with help of some existing example.Please suggest me some way so i can use spatial index in my spring data neo4j project with spatialRepo